# Diagonal OpenGL lines lose vertical component?

Tags: opengl

I try to draw a diagonal but OpenGL shows it as a horizontal line, I don't know why.

Here is my code:

Setup OpenGL:

```
if (!SetWindowPixelFormat(hDC))
    return 0;

if (!CreateViewGLContext(hDC))
    return 0;


BOOL SetWindowPixelFormat(HDC hDC)
{
int iBPP = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, BITSPIXEL) * GetDeviceCaps(hDC, PLANES);

ZeroMemory(&m_pfd, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));

m_pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
m_pfd.nVersion = 1;
m_pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
m_pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
m_pfd.cColorBits = iBPP;
m_pfd.cDepthBits = 24;
m_pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

int pixelIdx = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &m_pfd);

if (pixelIdx <= 0)
    return FALSE;

if (!SetPixelFormat(hDC, pixelIdx, &m_pfd))
    return FALSE;

return TRUE;
}
```

Set frustum:

```
void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    double fWidth = 35.209655761718750;
    double fHeight = 22.964477539062500;
    double xc = 506654.83659999998;
    double yc = 7805600.7220999999;

    SetFrustum(cx, cy, fWidth, fHeight, xc, yc);
}

void SetFrustum(int width, int height, double fWidth, double fHeight, double xc, double yc)
{    
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

gluOrtho2D(xc - fWidth/2, xc + fWidth/2, yc - fHeight/2, yc + fHeight/2);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Draw 5 points below must be on a diagonal but OpenGL shows as a horizontal line:

```
void OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3d(506655.5111, 7805600.4781, 0);
    glVertex3d(506655.3184, 7805600.5478, 0);
    glVertex3d(506655.2220, 7805600.5827, 0);
    glVertex3d(506654.9330, 7805600.6872, 0);
    glVertex3d(506654.8366, 7805600.7221, 0);
glEnd();

glFlush();

SwapBuffers(pDC->m_hDC);
}
```

Comment: Try using other x,y coordinates and see what happens...

Comment: You're really abusing double-precision FP here :P Just because you can send OpenGL double-precision values, doesn't mean the GPU can keep that precision; most GPUs run at 32-bit FP or less. Try values that are much farther apart.

Comment: Where this enormous values came from? I mean, gluOrtho sets matrix so it will operate on pixel-size scale, do you have display with 800k+ resolution? Or, to rephrase the same question - what is a values of width and height?

Comment: I tried if y2 - y1 > 0.5 then OpenGL will be correct. I think may be this is round off problem of OpenGL

Comment: I got data from a real system. I also tried with gluPerspective, it is too. It also happen on other computers. Width and height are screen size

Comment: I mean, why are you using so large values? Aside from precision problems - it just doesn't making any sense. Your screen is obviously smaller then requested values.

Comment: The problem also happen with float. I made the app by VC++ on Visual Studio 2010

Comment: You can refer source code here https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B69St8bDcBlBZmtheTI5RkRkUW8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think there is misunderstanding here. What are xc and yc in your code and why their values are so close to your vertices? Why values are so huge, while screen is far smaller? Huge values fits badly, if you really have to use them (which i highly doubt) - you need to use cascaded coordinate system - e.g. int coordinates defining fixed-size square position and then float coordinates defining vertices relative to square; but it's so very unlikely you need this.

Comment: Please don't call a function "SetFrustum" when you're setting a ortho projection in it. A frustum is something very different (namely a frustum used as projection creates a perspective effect).

Answer (score 1):

You're simply and clearly running into a precision problem here. Floating point values are only approximate. You got a fixed number of significant digits (the mantissa) and an exponent telling the order of magnitude. Now you've got two very different orders of magnitude here: The order of magnitude the absolute values your numbers have (which are large-ish) and the order of magnitude those numbers vary (which are small-ish). If you throw 4 multiplications and 4 additions onto them (which is what happens when a vertex component gets transformed by matrix multiplication) your very smallish value variations will get lost within the numerical errors accumulating doing floating point operations. In your case your numbers eventually round off to the same integer, but if you're unlucky they actually jitter around.

It doesn't matter if you use single or double precision math here: Either a GPU doesn't support double precision at all or must be forced into it, which usually involves a lot of internal bit juggling to emulate it. When you're working with a GPU you effectively are limited to working with single precision.

Now I really wonder why your numbers are so odd? What is it what you try to draw, that you have such a large range of orders of magnitude in it?